# Azure Cache options

Tags: caching, azure

I'm trying to create a cache layer for my services on azure.

Through the portal, in the left submenu, there's a cache menu item. When I open this item, there's only two options:

1- redis on azure (preview)

[image]

2- create using powershell.

[image]

I'm looking forward redis on azure, but there's not an option on Brazil's datacenter, so I would have latency problems.

When I use 'help azure' on Azure Powershell, there's no option for "New-AzureManagedCache" as this link describe:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448831.aspx

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you don't have the latest Azure Cmdlets installed.  What you're looking for was added in May.

http://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases/tag/v0.8.1-May2014

Install the latest Azure Cmdlets and you should have it.